# How to build name detector in pandas

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

Here's my dataset

```
Id.   Text
1     Dear Mr. Alpha Terra, your food is delivered
2     Dear Mrs. Betta Irina Viruva, your drink is delivered
```

What I want is detect words after `Mr,`, or `Mrs,` but before `,`. So, I can get the name, there's what I want

```
Id.   Text                                                       Name
1     Dear Mr. Alpha Terra, your food is delivered               Alpha Terra 
2     Dear Mrs. Betta Irina Viruva, your drink is delivered      Betta Irina Viruva
```

Comment: Mentioning what have you tried could help.

Comment: I am using `str.extractall` with or category, but it not come to an end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html):

```
df['Name'] = df['Text'].str.extract(r'Mrs?\.\s+(.*?),', expand=False)
print (df)
   Id.                                               Text                Name
0    1       Dear Mr. Alpha Terra, your food is delivered         Alpha Terra
1    2  Dear Mrs. Betta Irina Viruva, your drink is de...  Betta Irina Viruva
```

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
In [134]: df.Text.str.split('.',expand=True)[1].str.split(',',expand=True)[0]
Out[134]: 
0            Alpha Terra
1     Betta Irina Viruva
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 2):

One option would be to match using the following pattern:

```
.*Mrs?\.\s+([^,]+).*
```

This will capture everything comma after `Mr.` or `Mrs.` up to, but not including, the first following comma.

```
line = "Dear Mrs. Betta Irina Viruva, your drink is delivered"
matches = re.match(r'.*Mrs?\.\s+([^,]+).*', line, re.M|re.I)

if matches:
    print "Name: ", matches.group(1)
else:
    print "No match!!"
```

### Demo

Comment: I bow down to your regex-fu

Answer (score 1):

As you are asking for regular expressions, try this:

```
import pandas
data = [{'ID': 1, 'Text': 'Dear Mr. Alpha Terra, your food is delivered'},
        {'ID': 2, 'Text': 'Dear Mrs. Betta Irina Viruva, your drink is delivered'}]
df = pandas.DataFrame(data)
df['Name'] = df.Text.str.extract(r'\.(.*?),')
print(df)
```

Here is a [repl](https://repl.it/repls/DefenselessChocolateMicrobsd) for you to try this out.

Comment: This works, at least for the sample data given, but would fail if the input had dots appearing other contexts.